# ImportXML / HTML Issues with Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets, google-directions-api

I'm struggling to get any results from an importxml to googlesheet.  I was previously getting output that reflected distance but now I'm getting an error "Imported content is empty."

```
 =importxml("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" & B9 & "&destination=" & D9 & "&sensor=false&alternatives=false","//leg/distance/value")/1000*0.621371
```

Does anyone know a workaround here?  I've also tried with my api key and had a similar issue:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=bay+shore,ny&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=XXXXXXX", "table",3)
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: 1. the sensor parameter is no longer required.  2. the key is now required (but needs to be enabled for the service you are using and have billing enabled with a credit card)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip, it was previously working earlier today.   For the key code that should only be via the importhtml, correct?  I have a valid api key that's been active for a few weeks.  I'm a total newbie and may be missing something.

Comment: I get a response from the second URL (when I append a valid key): text" : "50.7 mi", from [this url, plus key](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=bay+shore,ny&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=)

Comment: Great, I also get that.  What I'm having trouble with is having that distance populate in the google sheet.  I've tried multiple combinations of "table", 1-9 or "list", 1 -9.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a beginner attempt, so improvements welcomed, but looking at the URL posted by geocodezip you can pass that URL to `UrlFetchApp.fetch` and use `JSON.parse` on the `getContentText()` of the response.

You can use in sheet as user defined function and examine via console with `Logger.log(GETDISTANCE());`

```js
function GETDISTANCE() {
  
    var res= UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=bay+shore,ny&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=");
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    
    return json.rows[0]["elements"][0]["distance"].text;
}
```

You'd want to move the URL and location parts into parameters passed to the function to make it more versatile.

I determined the path to use to extract the mileage text by examining the JSON structure as shown:

[image]